# Putting food into a cli sheini on Shabbos

Tags: halacha, shabbat, melacha-creative-work, cooking-bishul

We know that a food that is a "davar yavesh" (dry) that was already cooked (in a cli rishon) before Shabbos may be put into a pot of hot water (even a cli rishon -- so long that it is on the fire) on Shabbos (See Orach Chaim [Siman 318 Saif 4](https://he.m.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%97#.D7.A1.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A3_.D7.93).)

We also know that in general a food that wasn't cooked may not be put even into a cli sheini (that is yad soledes bo) on Shabbos. The reason for this is either because we are afraid of "kalei habishul" foods that are easily cooked (even in a cli sheini) and since we don't know what foods are and what foods aren't we are therefore machmir by all foods. Or because of the reason that if the food wasn't cooked and now it's going into a cli sheini it could be considered "mechzei c'maveshel" (it "looks" like we are cooking.)

With this in mind, what would be the din if someone put a food in a cli sheini (that's yad soledes bo) before Shabbos. May it be put now into a cli sheini on shabbos?

If the food is considered to be from those that are "kalei habishul" then you could say that it's muter because it's already been cooked and would have the same din of a regular food that was put into a cli sheini. There is then no problem of actual bishul or even "mechzeh c'maveshel." However if the food is not considered to be from those that are "kalei habishul" (let's say we know for sure) and it was already in a cli sheini that was yad soledes so "something" happened to it. Would that be enough to take away the second problem of mechzeh c'maveshel when one puts it into a cli sheini that is yad soledes bo on Shabbos?

Comment: It depends on how cooked it was before shabbat came in.

Answer (score 1):

See Magen Avraham sk 14:

> (יד) מותר לשרותו:    אפילו בכ"ר וכמ"ש סט"ו דאין בישול אחר בישול וכ"כ התוספות והמרדכי ור"ן דלא כב"ח דמחמיר ומשמע מל' הש"ע דאם לא נתבשל מע"ש רק נשרה בחמין אסור לשרותו בחמין בשבת וטוב להחמיר אם היד סולדת בחמין & rlm;
>
> It seems from the Shulchan Aruch words that if something that was in a hot water pot before Shabbat, it is prohibited to put it a second time in a hot water pot on Shabbath.

See Mishnah Berurah sk 31:

> (לא) שנתבשל כבר - דוקא שנתבשל אבל אם לא נתבשל אלא נשרה מע"ש בכלי ראשון שהיס"ב אסור לשרותו בחמין שהיס"ב בשבת דאע"ג דאין כאן תוספת בישול מ"מ כ"ז שלא נתבשל ממש אלא היה בכלי ראשון ניתוסף בו קצת בישול כשמניחו פעם שני בחמין ויש מקילין בדבר ודעת הפמ"ג דהמקילין מיירי בדבר שדרכו וטבעו קל להגמר בישולו אף בכלי ראשון שהוסר מן האש אבל דבר שאין דרכו להתבשל לגמרי בכלי ראשון לכו"ע אסור וטוב להחמיר בכל גוונא ע"ש וכ"ז לענין לשרותו בכלי ראשון אבל לשרותו בכ"ש אף שהיס"ב יש להקל בכל גוונא כיון שבע"ש נשרה בחמין שהיס"ב: ‏
>
> There are people who are lenient. The Peri Megadim explained that this leniency is restricted to Kaley Habishul (as the O. P. purpose) because such things were already entirely cooked. But for Non-Kaley Habishul, each time they come back in hot water, an additional partial cooking occurs. **But concerning the OP, to put it in a Keli Sheni, it is entirely allowed.**

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood his question (which is very understandable, given its complexity). Your answer refers to a case where it was in a cli RISHON before shabbos, but the OP is asking specifically about where it was in a cli SHEINI before shabbos. In that case there is more reason to be potentially concerned with mechzeh cmevashel because it was never really cooked.

Comment: @  Jay after the discussion concerning kale habishul in MB I think that the pb is the same, but you are right I need to add a little paragraph